# nhtmlunit javascript not working

Tags: c#, javascript, backbone.js, htmlunit, marionette

I've been trying for hours to get nhtmlunit to render my backbone/jquery/marionette website, but having problems.

This is the code I am using.

```
var webClient = new NHtmlUnit.WebClient(new NHtmlUnit.BrowserVersion(com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion.Chrome));                
webClient.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webClient.ThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode = true;
webClient.ThrowExceptionOnScriptError = true;
webClient.WaitForBackgroundJavaScript(500000);
webClient.WaitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000000);
var page = webClient.GetPage(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
return Content(page.WebResponse.ContentAsString);
```

Nothing is working, not even a simple test where I just do a document.getElementById lookup.

I sometimes get an error about not finding a method inside jquery 1.7.2, but even when I use a browser version that doens't report the error, javascript never seems to execute?

It's like I'm always just looking at the raw response, not taking into account executed javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but i took the lattest version and got your code to work. I used my own Request.Url.AbsoluteUri